# Запустить .bat-файл с параметром средствами Python

Tags: python, bat

Есть батник, который делает определенные действия с текстовым файлом и запускается с параметром имени этого текстового файла:

```
example.bat 1.txt
```

Подскажите, плиз, как запускать этот процесс в цикле из питоновского кода.
Гугление дало разные способы, но все дают ошибку

> "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
> specified"

Answer (score 2):

> разные способы

Есть только один способ:

```
os.system(command)
    Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.
```

А ошибка, которая Вам выдаётся:

> FileNotFoundError

говорит сама за себя. Вы знаете, что такое "текущий рабочий каталог"? Так вот, когда Вы запускаете свою программу, то текущим рабочим каталогом
становится тот, в котором расположена Ваша питон-программа. А где расположен файл *example.bat*?

Если в том же каталоге, что и программа, то напишите так:

```
os.system("./example.bat")
```

А если в другом, то так:

```
os.system("<Полный путь в каталог>/example.bat")
```

Comment: Да, батник в том же каталоге, что и питон. Запустит ли Ваш код батник с параметром?

Comment: Все-таки Ваш способ не единственный - добавил решение, которое сработало.

Comment: - Запустит ли Ваш код батник с параметром?

os.system("./example.bat 1.txt")

Answer (score 0):

Решилось так:

```
import subprocess

f = '1.txt'

subprocess.call(f'example.bat {f}', shell = False)
```